# Null values in qtablewidget

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, pyqt, qtablewidget

I develop a desktop application on PYQT5 with integration of posgtresql. I stumbled over the situation that the table does not display the values:

[image: looks like on screen]

source code:

```
def createTable(self):
    self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()

    conn = psycopg2.connect('host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=12345678')

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM wave_params")
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    for i in result:
        print(i)

    rows = len(result)
    columns = len(result[0])
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(columns)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(rows)

    index = 0
    while query != None:
        self.tableWidget.setItem(index,0, QTableWidgetItem(query.result[0]))
        # self.tableWidget.setItem(index, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(1))))
        # self.tableWidget.setItem(index, 2, QTableWidgetItem(str(query.value(2))))
        index = index + 1



    # table selection change
    self.tableWidget.doubleClicked.connect(self.on_click)

@pyqtSlot()
def on_click(self):
    print("\n")
    for currentQTableWidgetItem in self.tableWidget.selectedItems():
        print(currentQTableWidgetItem.row(), currentQTableWidgetItem.column(), currentQTableWidgetItem.text())
```

I can not understand. what is the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: [QTableWidgetItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#public-functions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the cursor object has no attribute result.
in your code result is a list of tuples containing the return value of `cursor.fetchall()` and query is the return value of `cursor.execute()`. `cursor.execute()` returns always None 
(see [documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html)). You only need to loop over result, here 2 examples:

```
def createTable(self):
    self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self)

    psycopg2.connect('host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=12345678')

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ladestelle")
    result = cursor.fetchall()

    rows = len(result)
    columns = len(result[0])
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(columns)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(rows)

    for i, r in enumerate(result):
        self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 0, QTableWidgetItem(r[0]))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(r[1])))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 2, QTableWidgetItem(str(r[2])))
    '''
    # or simpler
    for r in range(rows):
        for c in range(columns):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(r, c, QTableWidgetItem(str(result[r][c])))
    '''

    self.tableWidget.doubleClicked.connect(self.on_click)
```